# Exploding/superhot capacitor in XT AC-DC PSU

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, rectifier

I have a commercial replacement PSU that I am using for a vintage XT class computer which has 4 DC lines (5v, 12v, -12v and -5v). On fitting the PSU however, the PC operated but after a while under load one of the capacitors E7 within the 5V DC section got very hot and vented, followed by a second E13 within a different line. The seller has given me some advice and kindly sent me a schematic. From this I have replaced the caps with rubycon 35V versions and E7 gets to about 50c tops from my testing, E13 barely get's warm. I will fit a fan. I wondered if anyone here from the schematic could please give me there thoughts on if there is a reason one failure led to the other? Many thanks

The specs for the replacement are approximately correct. The PSU can supply
+5v @6A,
+12v @ 3A,
-12v @ .8A,
-5v @ .8A

My PC is needing (tested via shunt resistor)
+5v @ 2.1A
+12v @ .34A
-12v @ .02A
-5v @ 0A

[image: Picture of schematic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The power supply schematic indicates this is a flyback converter, total output power rating = 80W (sum of output power rating of all rails), which is quite modest by today's standards.  Your load, however, is only about 12.6W.

Failure of E7 (on the +5V rail) is quite understandable, as it was subjected to the most stress (ripple current).  Even more understandable if this capacitor was several decades old - it would likely to have suffered "drying out" and its capacitance and ripple current withstand would have suffered as a result.

Failure of E13 (on the -5V rail) is less understandable, since there was no load on it, however, once E7 failed then E13 may have been subjected to higher ripple current and/or ripple voltage (and possibly DC voltage) than normal since E7 would have been providing the majority of the voltage clamping - details would depend on the magnetic coupling between each of the secondary winding pairs.

You mentioned that the replacement for E7 got to 50C - that is of some concern since it is not necessarily the temperature ***per se*** that does the damage, it is the **temperature rise above local ambient**.  Check the datasheet of the capacitor used, which will provide guidance on the effect of (a) ambient temperature, and (b) temperature rise.

I would be tempted to replace E7 with two or possibly three capacitors in parallel, to get the ripple current stress down - ripple current is what casues most of the internal heating.  Reducing ripple current by factor of 2 reduces the power loss by a factor of 4 (power = I^2 * R).  Look up electrolytic capacitor datasheets to ensure the ripple current stays within manufacturer specifications.  For these applications, the value of the capacitance is not as important as the ripple current withstand.  There is a second filter after E7, E7 is intended to filter the flyback ripple current and get +5V supply voltage ripple to an acceptable level that is then cleaned up by L2 & C8.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "not the temperature per se that does the damage"? Most thermal failures are related to absolute temperature.

Comment: @Hearth  A capacitor running at 80C when local ambient is 20C is going to have a much shorter life than the same capacitor running at 80C when local ambient is also 80C.

Comment: @FabioBarone Interesting. I never thought about it like that, and I'm a little sceptical. As I understand it, electrolytical capacitor aging is largely due to the electrolyte drying out, which happens faster at an elevated temperature. To my understanding, it does not matter much if this temperature is ambient or caused internally. Do you have a source with more information?

Comment: By adding an additional capacitor in parallel to E7 (in order share the ripple current) I believe this would also double the capacitance value, so should I get new caps ~500uF to keep an overall 1000uF? Thanks

Comment: @Willinliv  Yes, for capacitors in parallel the total capacitance is the sum of the individual C values.  When selecting caps for filtering the output of a flyback, the trick is it know the ripple current (RMS), and select capacitors that will provide the lifetime required at that current stress.  Reputable manufacturers will provide that data, if the data does not exist then assume the worst.  You can try to keep overall C the same as per the original design but that is secondary to achieving lifetime at the current stress.

Comment: @Hearth  re: ambient vs internal temperature: Suggest looking up the issue of "hotspot temperature".  Most manufacturers define lifetime in terms of **hotspot temperature**, which is not the same as external surface temperature.  Unless very special steps are taken, the internal hotspot temperature cannot be directly measured, it can only be estimated from a thermal model, and the accuracy of this model worsens as the internal power dissipiation increases (as ripple current increases, and as surface temperature rise above ambinet increases).

Answer (score 2):

The circuits are unrelated in a sense, but also coupled through the flyback transformer.

Both of these caps were 1000uF 16V, maybe there is a design error or manufacturing error, and cap model not handling enough ripple current was manufactured in for both circuits.

Also the fact that new ones you bought are of some specific brand means very little. Sure they could be quality capacitors, but if they have inadequate specs for the job they need to do, then being a good quality capacitor is not enough, as caps have various other parameters too, other than capacitance and voltage.